# Features rendering or Overriding

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

How to control features rendering or override between multiple layer.
I have tried this expression.

```
CASE
WHEN Count_distint(geomoverlaps('another_ layer', $geometry))=0
THEN to_string(rand(-5,5))+','+ to_string(-5,5)) 
ELSE '0.0,0.0'
END
```

and it's not working, then after notice that the expression are used only to 2 layers and me have multiple layers, I need your help to figure out this problems.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this expression and where exactly you are using it?

Comment: I need to control the features overlays between layers,  and I put the expression into the layer properties.

Comment: I don't think you can control the feature rendering order between different layer (you can order feature in the same layer but after that the layer order remain)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much.